# string replace do not replace character in string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string

```
var str = "this---is--- a --- test d ---";
```

I want to remove all the `-` and replace by nothing.

I tried using

```
var str = "this---is--- a --- test d ---";
var res = str.replace("-", "");
```

but res do not change...

if I do

```
var str = "this---is--- a --- test d ---";
var res = str.split('-').filter(e => !!e).join();
```

it does work.

Why the replace is not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `replace` will only replace one occurrence.

```
"aabc".replace("a", ""); // Outputs "abc"
"aabc".replaceAll("a", ""); // Outputs "bc"
```

Use `replaceAll` to replace all occurrences

```
var str = "this---is--- a --- test d ---";
var res = str.replaceAll("-", "");
```